# Can i send email without password using GoogleSignInApi and SMTP server(if possible) or in other way?

Tags: android

I am creating a simple android application for sending emails for blinds which works on voice input. Application does not interact with normal gmail/email application for sending mails. I used GoogleSignInApi to avoid invalid email id and static/dynamic input of senders email and password(security purpose). With GoogleSignInApi i am able to get email address but the major problem is i don't getting password from api because of this i am unable to send emails. Can i send email without using password in Android??
Thanks in advance..

MainActivity.java

```
private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
{
    if(result.isSuccess())
    {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        String name = account.getDisplayName();
        String email =  account.getEmail();
        String img_url=account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        Name.setText(name);
        Email.setText(email);
        Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_pic);
        updateUI(true);
    }
}
```

Config.java

```
//For storing email address and password of sender

public class Config 
{

    public static String EMAIL ="youremail@gmail.com";  //gmail address

    public static String PASSWORD ="passwd"; //password
}
```

SendMail.java

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    //Declaring Variables
    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private TextToSpeech t1;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
        t1=new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        t1.speak("Message Sent", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        //props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL,Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);

            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i send email without using password in Android?

No. Otherwise, spammers would just use Android devices to send their emails.

You are creating an email client. Email clients need the account credentials and server information (SMTP, IMAP, etc.) in order to send and receive emails.

You might consider adding your features to an existing open source email client (e.g., K9 Mail), or at least using one as a guide for the sorts of things that your app will need to be an email client.